# Horizontal slide out animation (like in Figma) in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, figma

I am trying to implement a horizontal slide-out animation on left-swipe in Flutter, kind of like the one available in Figma prototyping. Essentially, I would be having a stack of containers (with some text), and on left swipe of the top most container, that container should slide out revealing the underneath container (and so on).

So far, I have looked at PageView and Slide Transition widgets; PageView does not allow do this as the containers there are arranged like a list. Slide Transition requires a route and navigation to that route, which is not the case. Also, this has to be implemented on a Flutter Stack such that, the topmost container moves out. Any inputs on high-level widgets to achieve this / sample code would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Figma prototype of 'slide-out' where the overlaying container goes out along an ease-in curve while the underneath container comes into view with parallax]

Comment: `SlideTransition` requires `Animation<Offset>` - it does not require any `Route`

Comment: @pskink SlideTransition may not work if I want to update the location of the container as I drag (onPanUpdate)...The interaction is via drag

Answer (score -1):

Use this pub package to create horizontal slide-out animation.

[carousel slider package](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider)

```
      CarouselSlider(
        items: child as List<Widget>?,
        options: CarouselOptions(
          autoPlay: false,
          enlargeCenterPage: true,
          aspectRatio: 2.0,
          onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
            setState(() {
              _current = index;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
```

child can be Stack or Container, as you prefer.

Comment: Don't think this is applicable on a stack of containers

Comment: You can use it. Read package documnetation and see code in my edited answer.

Comment: It still doesn't work like Figma as the different items are placed adjacent to each other, whereas I want a top item, which when swiped should reveal an item underneath